# Create items last on backlog

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We would like new items to end up last on the backlog. I updated the WIT field Backlog Priority in the first transition and set that to 2000000 but it was changed back to a lower number automatically (with a 2nd revision)

Anyway this can be accomplished?

TFS 2015 update 3 on prem.

Thanks!

Comment: New items should appear at the bottom of the backlog already. Is there something else (like using Copy on the work item) that's providing a Stack Rank?

Comment: They will end up at the top of the backlog when you use quick add using the scrum template in the latest version. If you look at the history for the newly created item a rev 2 has been created by TFS to put it at the top.

Comment: Now a year and a half later, did you find a solution? Still, in TFS 18, new items are created at the selected item, and the selected item by default is the one at top, so new items are still created at top by default, breaking the top-is-most-priority rule. I somehow need an extra column, so I have New-Prioritized-Approved-Committed-Done, if this problem cannot be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as *nschonni* commented, new items will automatically appear at the last on backlog.

After you've got some items on your backlog, you can order them and create a prioritized list of work. Frequently reviewing and prioritizing your backlog can help your team know what's most important to deliver next.

Reorder your backlog by simply dragging work items. Or, if you prefer the keyboard, hold the Alt key and use the up and down arrows.

[image]

> You should **refrain** from using the bulk modify function to **change
>   the backlog priority of work items**. While you can assign a value to
>   the Backlog Priority (Scrum) or Stack Rank (Agile and CMMI) fields,
>   you'll be assigning the same value to all items you've selected for
>   bulk edit. **These fields are used by the system to track the relative
>   ranking of item**s on the product, feature, or epic backlogs.
>
> [Source Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/bulk-modify-work-items#backlog-order)

---

### Update

When you use the quick add, the new crated item either in the top or bottom is **based on the position of your mouse**.

For example, if you put the mouse at the top, the new created item should also at the top. If you put the mouse at the bottom, then it will also appear at the bottom. More if you want the created at a specific position, you just need to move your mouse.

[image]
***The select items should have a grey background.***

Comment: Thanks, it's created at the top using scrum template. I know we can reorder but if you have a long backlog it's tedious to do this manually (would be great with "Move to bottom" choice...).

Comment: It's weird, test with my TFS15 using scrum template. The new created will  appear  at the bottom. Are you using a default  scrum template or customize one?

Comment: @mansos I can reproduce your issue. Quiet easy, details please see my update answer.